# What happen if Cookie 'Expires/Max-Age' is 'N/A' or not set

Tags: cookies, asp.net-identity

I tried to increase the cookie expiry time and activated sliding expiry.

But the cookie expiry is still "N/A"

what problems will it cause, why expiry is not shown. In this case what will happen to cookie. when will it expire.

[image]

Answer (score 15):

It means the cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser closes, but not always).

> When user privacy is a concern, It is important that any web app
> implementation will invalidate cookie data after a certain timeout and
> won't rely on the browser clearing session cookies.
>
> One of the most beloved features of Firefox [prevents session cookies from ever
> expiring](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=345345). The [same issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128513) is also occuring with google chrome (and
> probably with other browsers offering similar features)